# Sound from radio to sound card's S/PDIF In isn't detected

Tags: linux, audio

When I had Linux Mint 17.1 KDE installed, I would capture music (using Ocenaudio – couldn't get Audacity to record) from an external Internet radio player / DAC to the computer's Xonar D2 sound card's  S/PDIF In and then edit using Audacity. Headphones are connected to the Xonar through which music from the radio would play. When editing I would play the music back with Audacity, then play the edited tracks with VLC to ensure everything was OK, always monitoring with headphones.

After upgrading to Mint 17.3, there was no longer any sound from the radio through the headphones, neither Ocenaudio nor Audacity would record the music, and there was no sound from music on the computer played by VLC through the headphones. I installed CentOS then openSUSE and these problems persisted.

Now I've installed and settled on Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon. There's been a partial resolution of the problems as there is now sound via the headphones when VLC plays music from the computer. However,  music from the radio still doesn't appear to be processed by the sound card because there's still no sound from the headphones and neither Audacity nor Kwave (Ocenaudio won't install) record the music.

I've double-checked that the cable from the radio's S/PDIF Out is properly connected to the Xonar's S/PDIF In.

Help would really be appreciated to fix the problem of the sound card not detecting music from the radio.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: D2 [Xonar D2], device 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: D2 [Xonar D2], device 1: Digital [Digital]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I’ve made some progress in that Audacity now records sound from the radio. Playback of the recording is audible through the headphones. This happened after changing .asoundrc configuration.

Previous .asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 3
}

ctl.!default { 
    type hw           
    card 3
}
```

Current .asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {       # 'pcm' channel defines output -- responsible for multiplexing multiple sound streams into a single hardware output channel    
    type plug        # handles multiplexing, format conversion  
    slave.pcm {
        @func getenv
        vars [ ALSAPCM ]
        default "hw:D2"
    }
}

ctl.!default {      # 'ctl' channel controls the hardware mixer volume & other settings
  type hw
  card D2
}
```

However the headphones still don’t detect radio sound through the Xonar D2.  In BIOS I disabled Audio Controller; that didn’t help, so I re-enabled it.

In System Settings > Sound > Output > Play sound through, both “Digital Output (S/PDIF) *Virtuoso 200 (Xonar D2)*” and “Virtuoso 200 (Xonar D2) Analogue Stereo” Test Sound plays sound though the headphones. Under Input > Record sound from “Digital Input (SPDIF) *Virtuoso 200 (Xonar D2)*”, Input level is registering sound.

So sound is definitely being processed by the Xonar from both the radio and the computer, and the headphones are detecting sound from the computer -- but not from the radio.

Might the .asoundrc require further modification? Anyone reading this who’s willing and able to help?